# How to create a shortcut/alias for the "NTFS for Mac" preference?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, dual-boot, ntfs, alias

I have a bootcamp Windows installed on my RMBP,
and I used to use the "Startup Disk" preference to boot into windows.
By click and drag the "StartupDisk.prefPane" from /System/Library/PreferencePanes/ to Desktop while holding Cmd+Option, an alias can be created on Desktop.

After installing "NTFS for Mac", [the bootcamp Windows partition disappeared from the Startup Disk preference](http://kb_wp.paragon-software.com/article/204). And I have to use the "NTFS for Mac" preference to select.

I want to create a shortcut for "NTFS for Mac", but there is no "NTFS for Mac" in /System/Library/PreferencePanes/.

Where is the "NTFS for Mac.prefPane" located if there is one? 
Or another way to create a shortcut for NTFS for Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OSX has two more locations where preference panes can reside:

- `/Library/PreferencePanes/` - This is where system wide 3rd party panes are installed. (The folder you looked in (`/System/Library/PreferencePanes/`) is reserved for core OS preference panes.)
- `~/Library/PreferencePanes/` - This is where user-specific panes are installed.

Search these two locations and if you find the *NTFS for Mac* preference pane there create a short cut as a link to the file.

Comment: /Library/PreferencePanes/NTFSforMacOSX.prefPane is what I'm looking for.